# Elasticsearch aggregation on latest documents

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, getlatest

I have a document which can be modified any number of times a day.
I've ordered these document in time series creating index for each day.
And each day would have multiple versions of the same document with different modified date.

Document sample:

```
{
  id: 1234,
  user: kc,
  subscriptions: [
    'paper1',
    'paper2'
  ],
  modified_date: 1466697434020
}
```

What I'm looking for is to get the latest documents in a particular time range for all users
and to apply aggregation on top of it.

That would give a result like, in the last week/month how many people are subscribed for each of the papers.

Using top_hits I was able to get the latest document for different users in a time range, but I cannot apply further aggregations on this set of data.